# how to running python on a txt file on windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I am a beginning programmer, and now I am learning Python by Google Python class on my Windows 8 laptop. I was writing a a `print_words(filename)` function that counts how often each word appears in the text and prints like this:

```
- word1 count1
- word2 count2
```

I had completed the function, but I don't know how to run this function on a txt file. There is another function in the same file as function I wrote that teach me how to do so. But I just cannot figure out what it means, and I always got `usage: ./wordcount.py {--count | --topcount} file`. The function is

```
def main():
  if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'usage: ./wordcount.py {--count | --topcount} file'
    sys.exit(1)

  option = sys.argv[1] 
  filename = sys.argv[2]
  if option == '--count':
    print_words(filename)
  elif option == '--topcount':
    print_top(filename)
  else:
    print 'unknown option: ' + option
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

does anyone know what this code means ? I appreciate your help if u can.

Comment: You need to fix your indentation above to the same as the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an option on the command line.  The script is looking for either `--count` or `--topcount` as the first argument. The second argument gives the file name. So since you want it run the `print_words` function, you should use this command to run the script:

```
./wordcount.py --count file
```

Where `file` is the name of the text file you want to count the words of.